# Attempted to call method "getDoctrine" on class (Symfony)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to create small application to read the record from the table by id using symfony/doctrine.
My steps:

1. Created controller
   (GS\OrderBunndle\Controller\CustomerCuntroller.php), route. Testing
   URL - it is working;
2. Creating Entity for customer table
   (GS\OrderBundle\Entity\Customer.php) with columns and
   getters/setters;

3) Created GS\OrderBundle\Entity\CustomerRepository.php (I am not sure why do I need it yet, it was automatically generated). Source code:

```
namespace GS\OrderBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CustomerRepository extends EntityRepository
{
}
```

4) Modified CustomerController.php:

```
<?php

namespace GS\OrderBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use GS\OrderBundle\Entity\Customer;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager; 

class CustomerController 
{

    public function indexAction($id)
    {
            $customer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('GSOrderBundle:Customer')->find($id);
               return new Response(
            '<html><body>Number: '.$id.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

And getting following error:

> Attempted to call method "getDoctrine" on class
>   "GS\OrderBundle\Controller\CustomerController".
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - UndefinedMethodException
>
> Stack Trace
>
> in src/GS/OrderBundle/Controller/CustomerController.php at line 13   -
>       public function indexAction($id)
>       {
>               $customer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('GSOrderBundle:Customer')->find($id);
>                  return new Response(
>               'Number: '.$id.''
>           ); Logs   -
>
> 1 error INFO - Matched route "customer" (parameters: "_controller":
>   "GS\OrderBundle\Controller\CustomerController::indexAction", "id":
>   "1784", "_route": "customer") DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request"
>   to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". DEBUG -
>   Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
>   CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedMethodException: "Attempted
>   to call method "getDoctrine" on class
>   "GS\OrderBundle\Controller\CustomerController"." at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\goodstuff\src\GS\OrderBundle\Controller\CustomerController.php
>   line 13 DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". DEBUG -
>   Notified event "kernel.request" to listener
>   "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
>   DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener
>   "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to extend Symfony's `Controller` class to be able to use `getDoctrine()` method.

So:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class CustomerController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction($id)
    {
            $customer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('GSOrderBundle:Customer')->find($id);
               return new Response(
            '<html><body>Number: '.$id.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

(you can also [define controller as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) but this is more complex solution)